# How do I install virtio GPU guest drivers for ARM/aarch64 Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, gpu-driver, qemu, arm

I am using qemu (UTM) to run a Ubuntu virtual machine on an Apple Silicon device. The guest operating system is the ARM/aarch64 version of Ubuntu 22.04.

I would like to be able to use virtio to allow the ARM Ubuntu guest to utilize 3d acceleration. Therefore, I chose the "virtio-ramfb-gl (GPU supported)" graphics device option when setting up the virtual machine.

UTM informed me that "guest drivers are required for 3d acceleration."

**How do I install the necessary virtio GPU guest drivers onto my ARM/aarch64 Ubuntu guest?**

Answer (score 2):

It's already installed with Ubuntu Desktop. But it's buggy and not reliable. https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/4983

```
$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0x1af4)
    Device: virgl (ANGLE (Apple, Apple M1, OpenGL 4.1 Metal - 83)) (0x1010)
    Version: 22.2.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 0MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: compat (0x2)
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 2.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: virgl (ANGLE (Apple, Apple M1, OpenGL 4.1 Metal - 83))
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```